# How can I do this C++ question by using XOR operator for 2 or more digits number

Tags: c++, arrays, search, operators

XOR is working fine for single digit inputs but totally messes up while using 2 or more digits number. How can I still make this program by using XOR ?

This is the question basically :

Find the Missing Number

You are given a list of n-1 integers and these integers are in the range of 1 to n. There are no duplicates in list. One of the integers is missing in the list. Write an efficient code to find the missing integer.

My program is:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int n; //number of elements

    cout << "Enter the number of elements : ";
    cin >> n;

    //Declaring array
    int arr[n-1];

    //Taking input
    for(int i = 0; i<n-1; i++)
    cin >> arr[i];

    //printing array
    cout << "\nElements are :";
    for(int i = 0; i<n-1; i++)
    cout << " " << arr[i];

    //Declaring elements to take XOR
    int x1 = arr[0]; // first element of array
    int x2 = 1; //first element in natural number series i.e 1,2,3,4...

    //taking XOR of all elements of the given array
    for(int i = 1; i<n-1; i++)
    x1 ^= arr[i];

    //taking XOR of all the natural numbers till 'n'
    for(int i = 2; i<arr[n-1]; i++)
    x2 ^= i;

    //Finally printing the output by taking XOR of x1 and x2
    //because same numbers will be removed since (A^A) = 0 also (A^0) = A
    cout << "\nMissing number : " << (x1^x2) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The above program doesn't work for the input below:

```
10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 10
```

Comment: Unless I misunderstand the problem, your algorithm doesn't work for single digits either: https://ideone.com/gAeFzF

Comment: `int arr[n-1];` uses VLA extension, and so is not valid C++.

Comment: You have out of bound access with `arr[n - 1]` -> UB.

Comment: The list of natural numbers is not `for( int i = 2; i < arr[n-1]; i++ )` it is `for( int i = 1; i <= n; i++ )`

Comment: @Nusakan: Seems correct, the input is for a list that is missing one number.

Comment: @Ben Voigt yep. completely missed the `int arr[n-1];`

Comment: @Nusakan: Of course, that's a VLA (illegal in C++)

Comment: @BenVoigt Sir if VLA is illegal then what is the alternative of using variable array ?

Comment: Dynamic allocation, you can use either `std::unique_ptr<int[]> arr = std::make_unique<int[]>(n-1);` or `std::vector<int> arr(n-1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loops are wrong, you can change to:

```
//Declaring elements to take XOR
int x1 = 0; // for element of array
int x2 = 0; // for natural number series i.e 1,2,3,4...

//taking XOR of all elements of the given array
for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    x1 ^= arr[i];

//taking XOR of all the natural numbers till 'n'
for (int i = 1; i != n + 1; i++)
    x2 ^= i;
```

Note that natural number range is bigger than arr size.